# How to convert Date into UTC in MongoMapper & Ruby/Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, date, utc

I added this line of code

```
self.auth_history.push [start_date, self.coupon_code]
```

And got this error message

```
Date is not currently supported; use a UTC Time instance instead.
```

I also tried `start_date.utc`, but it didn't work either.

Please help.  Thanks.

Comment: try Time.new(start_date) , where start_date come from ? it's a method ?

Comment: I gave up on converting start_date from Date to a UTC Time.  I'm just going to store start_date (a Date) as a string by using start_date.to_s

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got this answer from Seattle Brigade group -

===

I didn't see start_date defined in your code as a key in MongoMapper, so
I'll assume you're creating your own date object, either directly via Ruby,
or wrapped by Rails. As far as I know, and someone please correct me, Mongo
stores dates as UTC time in milliseconds since epoch. So when you define a
key with a :date mapping in MongoMapper, you're wrapping a Time object in
Ruby.

Therefore, if you want to store a date inside of Mongo, and it wasn't
created by MongoMapper, make sure you create a Time object in UTC.
MongoMapper comes with a Date mixin method called to_mongo that you can use.

```
>> Time.now.utc
=> Fri Jan 28 03:47:50 UTC 2011
>> require 'date'
=> true
>> date = Date.today
=> #<Date: 4911179/2,0,2299161>
>> Time.utc(date.year, date.month, date.day)
=> Thu Jan 27 00:00:00 UTC 2011
>> require 'rubygems'
=> true
>> require 'mongo_mapper'
=> true
>> Date.to_mongo(date)
=> Thu Jan 27 00:00:00 UTC 2011
```

But watch out for the time change.

```
>> Date.to_mongo(Time.now)
=> Thu Jan 27 00:00:00 UTC 2011
>> Date.to_mongo(Time.now.utc)
=> Fri Jan 28 00:00:00 UTC 2011
```

Good luck.

===

And by using

```
Date.to_mongo(start_date)
```

it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think the question title is bad in description. Actually, the difference between different timezone is on Time not on Date. So, it's really not proper to say I want to convert a date to UTC format.

Here is another way in Ruby to convert DateTime to its UTC format:

```
DateTime.now.new_offset(0)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's another option:

```
Time.at(Date.today.to_datetime.to_i).utc
```

Here I am using `Date.today` as an arbitrary example date. Replace with whatever date you want to convert. Once the date is converted to a `Time` instance, it can be serialized to `BSON` without any problem, as `Time` is a supported primitive type, that is to say, it can be saved using MongoMapper to the database.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I have rolled back an edit to my answer that totally changed my code (i.e., the edit resulted in the code returning a DateTime, not a Time instance. I also added an explanation of how this pure ruby solution relates to MongoMapper.

Answer (score -2):

As per EfratBlaier's comment I have updated the answer.

Date.today.to_time.utc

Comment: That method is to_datetime, not to_date_time.

Comment: This can be wrong because you usually want the date in UTC. This will first convert it to midnight local time, then give you that time in UTC.