# Convert local time to UTC in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone

In my MySQL database the updated_at field is being stored as UTC.  Last week a record was entered at 7pm EDT and it's updated_at value is "2012-08-01 23:00:00".  I'm trying to convert local time for a web client to UTC that can be compared against the updated_at field in the database.

As an example, I'd like to convert '08/01/2012 07:00 pm' to '2012-08-01 23:00:00' (accounting for me being in EDT) but I'm missing the time zone aspect to the conversion.  '7:00 pm' is local time and could be from any time zone.  My current code:

```
ruby-1.9.2-head :015 > from_date = DateTime.strptime('08/01/2012 07:00 pm', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')
=> Wed, 01 Aug 2012 19:00:00 +0000 
ruby-1.9.2-head :016 > from_date = Time.zone.parse(from_date.to_s).utc
=> 2012-08-01 19:00:00 UTC
```

Any thoughts?

Edit: Also, I could use "%Z" in my strptime call but that's assuming I have the timezone in the value, which I currently do not. I guess I could use Javascript to send that along with the date/time value.

Comment: Would this hep you?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820819/how-to-convert-date-into-utc-in-ruby-rails

Answer (score 43, accepted):

local to utc

`created_at.utc`

utc to local

`created_at.localtime`

Answer (score 1):

First I would check your time zone setting.

In your environment.rb (Rails 2) or application.rb (Rails 3) file, you can set the default timezone with: `config.time_zone = 'Eastern Daylight Time (EDT)'`

Secondly I would look at this post for information and guidance and tips to meet your needs:
http://databasically.com/2010/10/22/what-time-is-it-or-handling-timezones-in-rails/

Comment: I don't have a timezone explicitly set, so it's defaulting to UTC.  If I change that to default to EDT now, would that affect the data that has already been stored in the database?

Comment: This is basically correct except that isn't a valid time zone.  That's a time standard.   ```"Hawaii", "Alaska", "Pacific Time (US & Canada)", "Arizona", "Mountain Time (US & Canada)", "Central Time (US & Canada)", "Eastern Time (US & Canada)", "Indiana (East)"```