# Scheduled Posting in Ruby on Rails - How to use Server time instead of Local time filled by datepicker ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am doing scheduled posting of emails and this is what I have in my controller

```
@email.post_at = Time.parse(params[:email][:post_at]).in_time_zone(Time.zone)
```

Now the person selects time through jquery datepicker and enters submit.But the action do not take place at the scheduled time and takes at UTC - THE_LOCAL_TIME_ZONE, for example, if you are in France, the mail will be posted after 1 hour.

This is what I have on my server

```
 => #<Email id: 42, Body: "Test Email", created_at: "2013-06-02 16:58:19", updated_at: "2013-06-02 16:58:19", post_at: "2013-06-02 17:58:19", user_id: 17>
```

I want the created_at and post_at to be same (post_at is coming from datepicker)

I have tried

```
@email.post_at = Time.parse(params[:email][:post_at])
@email.post_at = Time.parse(params[:email][:post_at]).in_time_zone(Time.zone)
@email.post_at = Time.parse(params[:email][:post_at]).in_time_zone("UTC")
```

but all 3 are giving me same problem. Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.It may give solution.

[How to convert Date into UTC in MongoMapper & Ruby/Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820819/how-to-convert-date-into-utc-in-ruby-rails)